# Database Mail Stop Working

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, database-mail

SQL Server 2016 Enterprise Edition SP1

Database Mail was working fine with no problem until a server patching was performed. I tried to do all the [troubleshooting](http://expressnetsolutions.com/sqldch/?p=683) available but still all mails got queued and no records in the log.

Finally when I checked the database mail program I  didn't find the executable file in the Binn folder or any other folders!

My questions are how this happened and how to solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this Microsoft link which mentioned that this is a bug in SQL Server 2016 SP1 CU

[https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3186435/sql-server-2016-database-mail-doesn-t-work-when-net-framework-3-5]

This was resolved by installing ,net framework 3.5

Answer (score 3):

I certainly can't explain why any Windows patching would remove executables from your Binn folder; that sounds more like the work of "security" software or manual intervention.

In any case, there are a couple of things you can try:

- run setup and try a repair against the SQL Server installation. Maybe start with just the shared components.
- copy the missing files from the Binn folder of another installation that works and is the **exact** same edition and `@@VERSION`. If you don't have one of these readily available, you could probably install Evaluation Edition on your workstation or a VM. But really you should have a mirrored installation somewhere that matches production so that you can test Windows patching and any other updates **there first** before you "try it out" in production.